# How can I add a Colored Highlight/ Rectangle Behind a Word, but with the Orientation and Dimensions of the Highlighted Rectangle Manipulated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so the current highlighted orange on the words software engineer is lowered, so that the top edge ends 40% of the way up the text and the bottom of the highlight is extended below the words and extends slightly to the right.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const welcomeText = document.getElementById("welcome-text");
  const container = document.querySelector(".welcome-container");
  const welcomeScreen = document.getElementById("welcome-screen");
  const portfolio = document.getElementById("portfolio");
  const characters = welcomeText.textContent.split("");

  welcomeText.textContent = ""; // Clear the original text

  characters.forEach(function(char, index) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = char;
    span.style.transitionDelay = index * 0.125 + "s"; // Delay each character's transition
    welcomeText.appendChild(span);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    welcomeText.classList.add("animate-color");
    setTimeout(function() {
      welcomeText.classList.add("animate-slide");
      container.style.height = welcomeText.offsetHeight + "px"; // Adjust container height dynamically
      setTimeout(function() {
        welcomeText.style.opacity = "0"; // Set opacity to 0 to fade out the text
        setTimeout(function() {
          welcomeText.textContent = ""; // Clear the text content
          welcomeText.style.opacity = "1"; // Set opacity back to 1
          welcomeText.style.color = "rgb(57, 55, 55)"; // Change color back to the original color
          welcomeScreen.style.zIndex = "-2"; // Hide the welcome screen
          welcomeScreen.style.backgroundColor = "none"; // Hide the welcome screen
          portfolio.style.display = "block"; // Show the hidden content
        }, 600); // Delay for 0.3 seconds to complete the fading effect
      }, 500); // Delay the fading animation for 1 second
    }, characters.length * 0.125 * 1000); // Delay the slide animation until color transition is complete
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Welcome Screen */

#welcome-screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.welcome-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#welcome-text {
  font-size: 86px;
  color: rgb(57, 55, 55);
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.animate-color span {
  transition: color 0.3s linear;
  color: white;
}

.animate-slide {
  animation: slide-animation 1s 0.5s forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slide-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  99% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* Portfolio */

#portfolio {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Header */

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: auto;
}

header p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

header ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.underline {
  position: relative;
}

.underline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 98, 0);
  border-radius: 6px;
}


/* Page Hero */

.page-hero {
  background-color: black;
  height: 825px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#writing-container {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 175px;
}

#ph-p-container {
  width: 40%;
}

#ph-h1-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

#ph-h1-container h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#ph-h1-container h1 .highlight {
  background-color: rgb(255, 98, 0);
}

#page-hero-svgs {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}

.svg-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" preload>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin preload>
<link rel='preload' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@400;700&display=swap" as='style'>
<!-- Welcome Screen -->

<div id="welcome-screen">
  <div class="welcome-container">
    <h1 id="welcome-text">Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio -->

<div id="portfolio">

  <!-- Header -->

  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <p>Jake Matthews</p>
      <ul>
        <li class="underline">About</li>
        <li class="underline">Projects</li>
        <li class="underline">Future Plans</li>
        <li class="underline">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>

  <!-- Page Hero -->

  <div class="page-hero">
    <div id="writing-container">
      <div id="ph-h1-container">
        <h1>Hi, I'm Jake | <span class="highlight">Software Engineer</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="page-hero-svgs">
        <img src="./images/github-svg.svg" alt="" id="github" class="svg-icon">
        <img src="./images/linkedin-svg.svg" alt="" id="linkedin" class="svg-icon">
        <img src="./images/email-svg.svg" alt="" id="email" class="svg-icon">
      </div>
      <div id="ph-p-container">
        <p>I am passionate about creating beautiful, immersive & interactive websites – whilst implementing the latest, most powerful/ capable libraries and frameworks. I have a thirst for pushing my capability ceiling. I am also passionate about forex trading
          – I have had live funded accounts provided by proprietary trading companies after passing evaluation tests.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Rest of Site -->

  <div id="rest-of-site">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jake-matthews/pen/NWEqNaW

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've created a running snippet from your posted code in order that those that wish to compose an answer have the relevant code to do so (in future, please do this yourself). While I've removed some of the unnecessary parts of the code, that the Snippet adds for you, I've left everything mostly intact and unaffected. Could you please take out everything that's not relevant to the specific question you're asking (there's way too much CSS, HTML and - possibly - JavaScript for us to filter through for the relevant parts).

Comment: @DavidThomas apologies, I'm new. Noted though

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Would box-shadow (which can be inset) help?

Comment: Hi, @AHaworth

Your suggestion did the trick, I was just wondering about it when I went away from my cpu also haha. 

Thank you

.highlight {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -27.25px 0 rgb(255, 98, 0);
}